# What is the best way to align a paragraph beside an image?

Tags: website-design, text, image, alignment

The webpage has small paragraphs (5-6 lines) with images on the right of each paragraph. The text in paragraph is left aligned. The paragraph is not always as big as the height of the image that is on its right. What is the best way to align the paragraph with the image - top aligned or centre aligned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I do not have an example of your layout, I would personally choose top aligned in this case. This will probably give the most visual order and harmony, especially since your paragraph block text is also left aligned (meaning you already have an unconsistent visual area on the right).

Compare:

[image]

Comment: Agree. because this is suitable for both variable size of paragraph or fixed size of paragraph.